# Azure file shared storage in Kubernetes pod checks default namespace for secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am following [setting up the Azure File share to the pod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume).

- created the namespace
- created the secrets as specified
- pod configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-storage-pod
  namespace: storage-test 
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:latest 
    name: test-storage-pod
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azure
        mountPath: /mnt/azure-filestore
  volumes:
  - name: azure
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-storage-secret
      shareName: appdata/data
      readOnly: false
```

- `kubectl describe -n storage-test pod/<pod-name>` or `kubectl get -n storage-test event`

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON        OBJECT                 MESSAGE
2m13s       Normal    Scheduled     pod/test-storage-pod   Successfully assigned storage-test/test-storage-pod to aks-default-1231523-vmss00001a
6s          Warning   FailedMount   pod/test-storage-pod   MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure" : Couldn't get secret default/azure-storage-secret
11s         Warning   FailedMount   pod/test-storage-pod   Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[azure], unattached volumes=[default-token-gzxk8 azure]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Question:

- the secret is created under the namespace storage-test as well, is that Kubelet first checks the storage under default namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are working default namespace, that's why Kubelet first checks the default namespace. Please try to switch to your created namespace with the command:

> kubens storage-test

Try to run your pod under storage-test namespace once again.

Comment: Yeah when i use `kubectl -n namespace apply -f pod-definition.yaml` i don't see that event, looking the default namespace. Though i have already specified the namespace in the pod definition yaml.

Comment: Hello @Tim. Have you tried my sollution or you've managed this in other way? It's not clear for based on your comment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed it by passing the name space to the kubectl command. `kubens` is not recognized it might be a alias or utility not sure. I can also override the namespace in the context as well `kubectl config set-context --current --namespace storage-test`.

Comment: @Tim, yes, using --namespace is the option if you don't switch to active namespace with the comand `kubens`. Could you please accept the answer? Thanks.